# How to Display returned mystring value as date in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a function to get absent days based on absence entries in my attendance sheet.

My code is:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim myString As String

'Loop through all the cells in the range
For Each cell In myRange
    'Check for value
    If cell = "A" Then
        myString = myString & Cells(myRow, cell.Column) & ", "
    End If
Next cell

'Return string
If Len(myString) > 0 Then
    AbsentDays = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 2)
End If

End Function
```

I want to display the returned values displayed as `"dd mmm"`.

Comment: what is the value and format you are getting now for `AbsentDays` ?

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use `myString = myString & Format(Cells(myRow, cell.Column), "dd mmm") & ", "` (if that cell contains a date)

Comment: I am getting like this : 6/7/2017, 6/9/2017, 6/15/2017, 6/16/2017  , but I want to get like 7 june , 9 june....

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `AbsentDays` is a `String`, and you are getting `6/7/2017, 6/9/2017, 6/15/2017, 6/16/2017` as a `String` (and not a `Date`).

Try the `String` conversion code below:

```
Dim AbsentDays  As String
Dim DatesArr As Variant
Dim i As Long

' for my tests
AbsentDays = "6/7/2017, 6/9/2017, 6/15/2017, 6/16/2017"

' use the split to get the values in an array
DatesArr = Split(AbsentDays, ",")
Dim myDateformat As Variant

' loop through array
For i = 0 To UBound(DatesArr)
    If i = 0 Then ' first array element
        myDateformat = Format(CDate(DatesArr(i)), "dd mmm")
    Else ' 2nd array element and above
        myDateformat = myDateformat & ", " & Format(CDate(DatesArr(i)), "dd mmm")
    End If
Next i

MsgBox myDateformat
```

Comment: I want to show it in excel rows. I am new in vba excel . can you type the full code.

Comment: @YowE3K is he getting an array of dates ? I thought these were example he is getting one by one

Comment: @YowE3K here you go, just for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Just because I like to keep changes to a minimum, I think you can simply change your line saying:

```
myString = myString & Cells(myRow, cell.Column) & ", "
```

to be:

```
myString = myString & Format(CDate(Cells(myRow, cell.Column)), "dd mmm") & ", "
```

Comment: LOL, don't forget to remove the "extra" `", "` at the end

Comment: @ShaiRado The existing code already does that.  (`AbsentDays = Left(myString, Len(myString) - 2)`)

Comment: can i send u the excel file. can you modify and help me

Comment: @PratyushKumar If my suggested change didn't work, there's not much I can help with even if I had a copy of the file. (Especially as I am going to bed in 7 minutes). What is happening when you try my code change?  What is happening when you add Shai's code to your code?  ("did not work" doesn't help much in diagnosing what went wrong.)

Comment: @PratyushKumar This might be a stupid question, but is `6/15/2017` a valid date in your country's date format?  (I'm struggling to think how `Format(CDate(Cells(myRow, cell.Column)), "dd mmm")` can leave the value looking like `6/15/2017`.)